# Selecting radiobutton from codebehind

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I have a set of three `RadioButtons` on my aspx page:

On `pageLoad` I am setting the default value from code behind using the following code:

```
rbListAccess.Items.FindByText("Page1ScoreCard POC").Selected = true;
rbListMetricType.Items.FindByText("Non-Percentage").Selected = true;
rbListMetricInterval.Items.FindByText("Monthly").Selected = true;
```

This is working fine.

On an edit link,I am fetching data from backend and setting values again using data columns from the dataset fetched but there it is not working. The values are not being selected correctly. I cannot understand the issue. Randomly once or twice one/two of the set are being set correctly:

```
rbListAccess.Items.FindByText(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ToBeFilledBy"].ToString()).Selected = true;
rbListMetricType.Items.FindByText(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["MetricType"].ToString()).Selected=true;

rbListMetricInterval.Items.FindByText(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["MetricInterval"].ToString()).Selected = true;
```

Please let me know the issue.

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see if the RadioButtonList is populated prior to setting the Selected property?

Comment: Make sure they are not being re-bound on the postback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to clear selection using `ClearSelection()` method before you assigning it a new value.

```
rbListAccess.ClearSelection(); // add this for all your radiobuttons
rbListMetricType.ClearSelection();
rbListMetricType.ClearSelection();

rbListAccess.Items.FindByText(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ToBeFilledBy"].ToString()).Selected = true;
rbListMetricType.Items.FindByText(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["MetricType"].ToString()).Selected=true;
rbListMetricInterval.Items.FindByText(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["MetricInterval"].ToString()).Selected = true;
```

Comment: can you post the entire function where you fetching the data from backend.